# When I highlight EditText content with BackgroundColorSpan, cursor is not visible

Tags: android, cursor, highlighting, android-edittext

How can I fix this issue?

Code:

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit); 
BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFAABBCC);
edit.getText().setSpan(span, 0, edit.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: You might consider, in the future, posting a code sample and screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the alpha value of the background color to lower value, for me 100 worked well.

Comment: this won't help when a specific color is needed, but otherwise — good to know :)